# How can I let my end user style an auto generated PDF invoice

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, styles

I have developed a site where users can create PDF invoices. However, these invoices aren't styled at all. They are built using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf, which converts the HTML view to a PDF.

Users have been asking me for a way to add, for instance their logo and some explanatory text which makes the invoice look more reliable.

How can I let them edit the template of an invoice?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Dompdf supports images according to https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf so have the users upload a logo?

Comment: do you mean that user only can use their logo and use the color that they love, don't you?

Comment: Logo upload is a simple step indeed. Bu I would like to go a little bit further, to give them more freedom over where to place the logo, add more text at the bottom, et cetera.

Comment: Dompdf accepts any HTML input, so it seems that you just need to generate the HTML file dynamically using different conditions. different CSS styles, and so on. I'm not familiar with Laravel, but I'm pretty sure you can achieve that with Blade.

Comment: How would you guys do this when for instance I would like my users to also define height, width, position, font size et cetera? It would almost become a document itself.